# Error in a standard library when incllude own header

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have a bytebuffer class, written in c++ by myself, i can compile it and it works as it should. Now i would like to use it in a big project, but when i include it in an another header, it throws an error if i try to build it. Here is the error:

```
  CXX    out.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/streambuf:808:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from /path/to/file/src/someheader1.h:29,
                 from /path/to/file/src/someheader2.h:31,
                 from /path/to/file/src/somesource.cpp:24:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf.tcc: In member function ‘virtual std::streamsize std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::xsgetn(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf.tcc:56:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf.tcc: In member function ‘virtual std::streamsize std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::xsputn(const char_type*, std::streamsize)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf.tcc:90:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:859:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:41,
                 from /path/to/file/src/someheader1.h:29,
                 from /path/to/file/src/someheader2.h:31,
                 from /path/to/file/src/somesource.cpp:24:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc: In member function ‘std::streamsize std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::readsome(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:693:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
make[4]: *** [out.o] Error 1
```

The skeleton of the header file in the project:

```
#ifndef _GUARD_
#define _GUARD_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

...

#include "bytebuffer.h"

namespace A {
  namespace B {

    using namespace std;
    using namespace A::C;

    class Myclass {
    public: 

    ...

     virtual void save( ByteBuffer& bb ) {
     }

     ...    

    } ;
  }
}

#endif
```

The byte buffer is realy simple, it contains a vector for data, and put and get methods for different types. If i comment out the save method in the header, nothing changes, so i don't even have to declare a byte buffer, it throws the error. What could cause this?

Comment: might be some naming conflict - have you tried without `using namespace`, and explicitly stating namespaces? Because it's usually not a good idea to clutter namespaces by using `using namespace` excessively ;)

Comment: Post someheader1.h, someheader2.h and somesource.cpp (up to the lines indicated in the error messages)

Comment: Take out the "..."s and post **real** code. Minimal, but enough to illustrate the problem. For example, most of bytebuffer.h is probably not relevant to the problem; incorporate just enough of it to produce the error. Oh, and names like `_GUARD_` that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are **reserved to the implementation**. Don't use them.

Comment: it's difficult to tell what is happening without more source (or at least more appropriate source). offhand I'd think you should be looking for a badly named #define that clashes with a name used by the system headers.

Comment: In the somesource file the indicated line is the first non comment line, and it is #include "someheader2.h" The someheader2 file is the skeleton which i alredy posted. Someheader1 is the header file of bytebuffer, the indicated line in it is #include<iostream>, and there is only the header guard, #include <vector>, and #include <string.h> before it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf.tcc:56:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

I happen to have this (hopefully) very same file around and line 56 is:

```
const streamsize __len = std::min(__buf_len, __remaining);
                              ^
                              col 38
```

I marked also the column 38, for the reader convenience.

Oh! The error talks about a `(` token but in this position there is not a `(` but a `min`. So my guess is that some header in your project is defining a macro `min`:

```
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

or similar.

The solution is to find this header, and remove the macro altogether (my favorite), or rename it (into `MIN`?), or else move the include of that header after all the standard includes (not always easy).

As a footnote, the MS ubiquitous `<windows.h>` is known for having such a macro... maybe someone copied a little?

Comment: Great telepathic work! :) I almost believe you've nailed it even without waiting for the OP to respond.

Comment: There were only 2 non-standard includes in somheader2.h, changing their order solved the problem... And yes, there is a waggish #define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b)) line in a third-party header, so i have to keep it.

Comment: @gberes: I forgot one alternative: `#undef min` ;)